# Unable to run Python .py from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

From Jenkins pipeline unable to run python scripts. Jenkins and the python scripts are on a aws ec2 instance

Added the snippet to Jenkins Pipeline node, jenkins is able to run the make file (meaning, it can start executing the makefile) but in jenkins Console Output, it errors out with  Python modules not found error. Same make file runs on the ec2 instance fine.

```
node {
    stage('Deploy') { 
        sh "(make -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-build-job/runpy)" 
    }
}
*******************************************
runpy makefile:
SHELL := /bin/bash

run:
        nohup /usr/bin/python3 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-build-job/aaa.py 2>&1 > aaa.out &
        nohup /usr/bin/python3 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-build-job/bbb.py 2>&1 > bbb.out &

******************************************
Error in the console output:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
******************************************
Printed sys.path from py:
When run on EC2: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-build-job', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-build-job', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

`-------'/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages'` is missing from the jenkins run (I can see Flask under this location)

--- added the path in .py using `sys.path.append("/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")`

DID NOT HELP, still seeing the module not found error :(

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, there is no flask module installed, where the code is being run.

I assume the code is run on master as I see no agent declaration in code. So, looks like your jenkins master doesn't have the required module installed.

Comment: Thank you @Sanket. I am able to resolve the moduleNotFound error by creating a virtualenv and creating jenkins and other python modules under ec2-user